# Rails ActionMailer with() params vs Parameters Directly on the Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

In Rails ActionMailer, you can send parameters to the mailer either by:

`with()` params:

```
Class MyMailer
  def send_something
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    ..
  end
end

MyMailer.with(user_id: user.id).send_something.deliver_now
```

or directly in the method call:

```
Class MyMailer
  def send_something(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    ..
  end
end

MyMailer.send_something(user.id).deliver_now
```

Are one of these methodologies preferred? Is there any advantage or disadvantage when the mailer is enqueued by a background job such as sidekiq which serializes all parameters to redis? I did note with https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html, they only show the with() params way to do this. Is one of these ways an older style?

Answer (score 0):

Using params is for sharing various things between methods. [ActionMailer::Parameterized API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized.html) explains that with an example.

> Provides the option to parameterize mailers in order to share instance variable setup, processing, and common headers.

It is not described in the guide.

Comment: As this is not answering the question just providing additional information, it is not suited as an answer. Once you earn enough reputation you'll be able to leave comments on posts